# Pandas compute means by group using value closest to current date

Tags: python, pandas

I'm attempting to compute the mean by date for all categories.  However, each category (called `mygroup` in the example) does not have a value for each date.  I would like to use an apply in pandas to compute the mean at each date, filling in the value using the closest date less than or equal to the current date.  For instance if I have:

```
pd.DataFrame({'date':['1','2','3','6','1','3','4','5','1','2','3','4'],
          'mygroup':['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','c','c','c','c'],
          'myval':[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120]})

   date mygroup myval
0   1   a   10
1   2   a   20
2   3   a   30
3   6   a   40
4   1   b   50
5   3   b   60
6   4   b   70
7   5   b   80
8   1   c   90
9   2   c   100
10  3   c   110
11  4   c   120
```

Computing the mean for `date == 1` should be equal to `(10 + 50 + 90)/3 = 50` which can be done with a typical mean apply groupby date.  However, for `date == 6` I would like to use the last known values for each `mygroup`.  The average then for `date == 6` would be calculated as

`(40 + 80 + 120)/3 = 80` since `a` has a value at `date == 6` of `40`, `b` does not have a value at `date == 6`, so the last known value was at `date == 5` which is `80` and the last known value for `c` was at `date == 4` of `120`.  The final result should look like:

```
date meanvalue
1    50
2    56.67
3    66.67
4    73.33
5    76.67
6    80
```

Is it possible to compute the mean by date with a groupby and apply in this manner, using each `mygroup` and filling in with the last known value if there is no value for the current date?  This will have to be done for thousands of dates and tens of thousands of categories, so for loops are to be avoided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df.set_index(['mygroup', 'date']).unstack().ffill(axis=1) \
  .stack().groupby(level=1).mean()

          myval
date           
1     50.000000
2     56.666667
3     66.666667
4     73.333333
5     76.666667
6     80.000000
```

- set your index to the key columns
- unstack the date level into columns
- fill the gaps horizontally - you have know a dense matrix you can calc against
- put the date back in
- group by date that is your expect output
- apply the math - here you want a mean

The key point to remember that's useful for a number of problems is that stacking / unstacking / pivoting, etc... *"rubikscubing"* your dataframe is always filling gaps of a sparse format (like the columnar format you have to begin with) into a dense one full of NAs.

So if you're able to do the calculation easily with a full dense matrix, then I encourage you to always focus first on obtaining that dense matrix, so that you can do the easy math afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert all implicit missing values to explicit and fill missing values with forward fill scheme and then do a normal groupby average:

```
from itertools import product
import pandas as pd

# get all combinations of date and mygroup using product function from itertools
all_combinations = list(product(df.date.drop_duplicates(), df.mygroup.drop_duplicates()))

# convert implicit missing values to explicit missing values by merging all combinations 
# with original data frame
df1 = pd.merge(df, pd.DataFrame.from_records(all_combinations, 
                                             columns = ['date', 'mygroup']), 'outer')

# fill missing date values with previous date values within each group
df1.sort_values(['mygroup', 'date']).ffill().groupby('date').mean()

#       myval
#date   
#1  50.000000
#2  56.666667
#3  66.666667
#4  73.333333
#5  76.666667
#6  80.000000
```